# MOSFET gate driver used without series capacitor

Tags: pwm, driver

I'm planning on using this drivers I bought [MD1213](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005713B.pdf) to drive [BUK7M45-40E](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK7M45-40E.pdf) MOSFETs and achieve fast PWM switching. Yet the drivers datasheet states the outputs are "Intended to drive the gate of an external MOSFET via a ***series capacitor***." Would connecting this drivers directly to the MOSFET gates work right or are this series capacitors present on the reference design compulsory?

Edit: This is the schematic, the driver output is connected directly to the MOSFET gate, with no other component in the same net.

[image: schematic of driver and mosfet connected]

Comment: if the BUK7M45-40E MOSFET is not connected to anything else, then you should not have any problems ..... any additional circuitry or power connection to the BUK7M45-40E MOSFET may cause problems ........... do you honestly believe that you included enough information?

Comment: Why did you pick this driver? "It is designed to drive high-voltage P-channel and N-channel MOSFETs for medical ultrasound and other applications requiring a high-output current for a capacitive load."  Is that your application?

Comment: @jsotola Thank you for answering, I've just uploaded my schematic, sorry for any other information that should have been included in my post !

Comment: @calcium3000 I'm trying to switch the MOSFETs as fast as possible, minimising switching losses by using low gate charge MOSFETs and high gate driving currents. The driver seemed to be cheap and capable of being wired even as a High-Speed level translator but I bought them on a hurry to get discount on them without studying the subject enough.

Comment: Be sure to use a GROUND PLANE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears that your circuit is well within the operating parameters of the driver without using output coupling capacitors. You have the sources of all the MOSFETs connected to the same ground (`pwmGND`) as VL of the driver, and VH is less than 13V. No problem.